# Ed25519 Successor to ECDSA in Bitcoin?

Tags: cryptography

Bitcoin is currently using the secp256k1 curve. Understand that Ed25519 is technically superior -- i.e., offers better security than ECDSA and DSA, speed and most importantly, I think, resistance against side-channel attacks.

Sia, Scorex, BigchainDB, Chain Core, Monero are some examples where ED25519 is used.

Understand that BIP32 made mention of Ed25519. Has BIP32 and/or ED25516 been implemented in Bitcoin or?

https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/cfrg/current/msg09115.html

https://datatracker.ietf.org/meeting/interim-2017-cfrg-01/materials/slides-interim-2017-cfrg-01-sessa-bip32-ed25519/

Nathan Aw